# Activate Google Earth offline?

Tags: google-earth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running google earth offline](https://superuser.com/questions/102187/running-google-earth-offline)

Anyone know if it's possible to run google earth with it never seeing the internet?

I have a dbCache.dat file from PC A that's 2Gb in Size, I also have the dat.Index file that goes along with it.  Now PC A has been on the internet before obviously.  I then disconnected it and I can use google earth offline with the dbCache file.

However , I have a second PC that I'll call PC_B.  PC_B installed google earth via a CD that the executable was downloaded to.  I then went and placed the cache file and index file in the appropriate spot.  However, when opening up google earth I am told that it can not connect to the Google Earth servers to activate the account.

Obviously I never want to put this machine on a networked connection.  Never want it to access the internet period.  So the question remains, can I activate google earth offline?

Comment: "Obviously I never want to put this machine on a networked connection." Not really, no. Is there a reason this machine is so critical that it can never, ever be connected to the internet, not even for a few minutes? What about getting patches? What are you going to do when you view a Google Earth tile at a location or zoom level you haven't encountered in the cache file?

Comment: @ceej; It's not our place to question his reasons, he probably has a very good one - and even if he doesn't, this is a Q and A site.

Comment: It's a Q&A site, and I'm Q'ing him. There are plenty of legitimate "don't do this unless you absolutely must" answers around here. We're talking about an application that is, at its core, an application that fundamentally relies on the Internet for its content.

Comment: @ceej; Very true, but I think GEarth is one of those things so obviously internet-dependant that it's safe to assume the asker knows it's internet-dependant, and doesn't want the dependacies :P

Comment: The machine can never be connected to the internet, period.  Not for 5 minutes...not for 5 seconds...not at all.  It's simple as that.

I have a 2GB Cache file that will suit me fine for what I need.  I'm not concerned about perfect images, so if I zoom in and missed a spot in the cache file then so be it.

Comment: I think this was pretty clearly answered the last time you asked almost the same question.  http://superuser.com/questions/102187/running-google-earth-offline  I don't see how you can avoid running this off a computer that was never and will never be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the same problem, and have chanced across the article at http://offlinegoogleearth.blogspot.com/

It covers both creating a download cache and making some registry changes to fool GE into thinking you have previously made an internet connection.

Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get the steps to work.  I suspect the reg setting is sensitive to the OS, so I need to create a Win2K virtual machine that I can connect to Google, then copy the reg settings to my target machine.

Comment: That was the answer...need to use regedit and add a few keys to fake GE out.  Once that's done you can point to the Cache file you got from a different machine.